# ACL in Node js based on relationships

Tags: node.js, permissions, npm, sequelize.js, acl

I'm trying to implement some kind of permission framework in Node js, using sequelize as an ORM (with Postgres). After hours of research, the closest thing I can find to do this with existing npm modules is using [acl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl) with acl sequelize to support my stack.

The problem is that it looks like the acl module assigns a role, where that role would get a set of permissions to **all instances** of a specific resource. However, I need to do permissioning for instances based on existing relationships of that user.

As an example, consider a permissioning system for a simple forum. It gives these permissions for each role:

```
    // allow guests to view posts
    acl.allow("guest", "post", "view");

    // allow registered users to view and create posts
    acl.allow("registered users", "post", ["view", "create"]);

    // allow administrators to perform any action on posts
    acl.allow("administrator", "post", "*");
```

Suppose that I want to also add the ability for registered users to also edit their own posts, and the user has a relationship to all the posts they've created.

Is there any way for this module to do this, or any other module that can support this kind of behavior on the database / ORM level?

If not, and I have to implement a custom one, what would the best approach to creating something like this.

Comment: You can try Node-Casbin: https://github.com/casbin/node-casbin. It supports ACL, RBAC, ABAC and other access control models.

Answer (score 5):

There is relatively new library [CASL](https://github.com/stalniy/casl). I'm the author of this library. And it's possible to implement your usecase quite easily:

```
const { AbilityBuilder } = require('casl')

const ability = AbilityBuilder.define((can, cannot) => {
  can('read', 'all')
  can(['update', 'delete'], 'Article', { author_id: loggedInUser.id })
})
```

The code above basically says:
- anyone can read everything
- anyone can update and delete articles where author_id equals logged in user id

Later you can do:

```
ability.can('delete', 'Post') 
//or
ability.can('update', post)
// where post variable is an instance of your Post model
```

Also there is an article which explains how to integrate CASL with MongoDB and Express exactly for your usecase.